# Why Spring Integration message method handling behavoiur is changed in default Spring Cloud Stream configuration

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-dsl

I have an application where Spring Integration (5.1.6 latest) is already used. And something like the following flow configured:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfigClass {
...
    @MessagingGateway(name = "someGateway")
    interface Gateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "inboundChannel")
        @Payload("T(java.time.ZonedDateTime).now()")
        void replicate();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel inboundChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow someFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(inboundChannel())
                .handle(someHandler())
                .channel(OUT)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeHandler someHandler() {
        return new SomeHandler();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SomeHandler implements GenericHandler<Object> {
    @Override
    public Message<List<String>> handle(final Object payload, 
                                        final MessageHeaders headers) {
        ...
        return MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(someList)
                .copyHeaders(headers)
                .setHeader("custom", customHeader)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine.

And if I try to find `integrationArgumentResolverMessageConverter` bean in context initialised I see next converters:

- `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`
- `ByteArrayMessageConverter`
- `ObjectStringMessageConverter`
- `GenericMessageConverter`

After that I add to my pom dependencies Spring Cloud Stream 2.1.2 dependency and Kinesis Binder 1.2.0. Configure bindings by default.

The application starts up but when I trying to process my existing flow it failed with something like:

> EL1004E: Method call: Method handle(java.time.ZonedDateTime,org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders) cannot be found on type p.a.c.k.a.g.e.SomeHandler   at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:225)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:134)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:390)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:90)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:365)
>       at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:160)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeExpression(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:664)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:655)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:491)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:362)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:106)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:93)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:169)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:151)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:143)
>       at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:413)
>       at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:533)
>       at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:473)
>       at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:463)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy444.replicate(Unknown Source)

And when I try to get the same `integrationArgumentResolverMessageConverter` bean from initialized context I see next chain:

- `ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter`
- `TupleJsonMessageConverter`
- `ByteArrayMessageConverter`
- `ObjectStringMessageConverter`
- `JavaSerializationMessageConverter`
- `KryoMessageConverter`
- `JsonUnmarshallingConverter`

And there is no `GenericMessageConverter`. As I understand it cannot be converted because of this converter missed (correct me please if I am wrong).

Why is the behaviour different when I just add Spring Cloud Stream default configuration? Or how to customize of using converters chain for specific flow? Or how to keep message conversation behaviour for different integration flow?

---

**Update:** So as I investigated spring cloud stream re-defines not only default integration `MessageConverter`s, but also it re-defines default `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`s, which is used to map method argument with a message..

Before additing Spring Cloud Stream:

- `HeaderMethodArgumentResolver`
- `HeadersMethodArgumentResolver`
- `MessageMethodArgumentResolver`
- `PayloadExpressionArgumentResolver`
- `NullAwarePayloadArgumentResolver`
- `PayloadsArgumentResolver`
- `MapArgumentResolver`
- `PayloadArgumentResolver`

After additing Spring Cloud Stream:

- `SmartPayloadArgumentResolver`
- `SmartMessageMethodArgumentResolver`
- `HeaderMethodArgumentResolver`
- `HeadersMethodArgumentResolver`
- `PayloadExpressionArgumentResolver`
- `NullAwarePayloadArgumentResolver`
- `PayloadExpressionArgumentResolver`
- `PayloadsArgumentResolver`
- `MapArgumentResolver`

There two deprecated `SmartPayloadArgumentResolver` and `SmartMessageMethodArgumentResolver` with fix for conversion from `byte[]` payload to `Object`. But what I cannot understand why there are two `PayloadExpressionArgumentResolver`?..

And the main question: why Spring Cloud Stream default application context affects Spring Integration default application context, I thought before that Stream's resolvers/converters were only related to message endpoints linked with stream destination channels...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why Stream drops that converter (could be a bug, maybe open a GitHub issue over there), but I believe you can add it back as a `@StreamMessageConverter` `@Bean` as discussed in the stream docs.

Comment: Thx @Gary Russell But as I understand I need to create `@IntegrationMessageConverter` (not for streaming) but I still afraid whether it may affect default conversion behaviour for streaming...

Comment: Hmmm - what makes you think that converter is involved? Your handler takes `Object` which implies no conversion is needed/performed. Can you edit the question to show the complete stack trace?

Comment: Actually it is strange for me why message handling behaviour changed, I don't want to touch existing integration config.. And regarding `@StreamMessageConverter` - as I understand it should be related only to the channel which directly link the kinesis stream. No?

Comment: @GaryRussell, no the dropping is not a bug, since in version 2.x of s-c-stream only custom converters which are annotated with `StreamMessageConverter` are added. That actually changed with 3.0.0.M3, where `StreamMessageConverter` has been deprecated and not used by the franework, but hat is the separate topic.

Comment: thx @OlegZhurakousky for your reply. But how to keep the behaviour of existing spring integration framework, when I added spring cloud stream framework?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, you claim you are missing a converter. If so, you define your converter as @bean in your config and annotate it with `StreamMessageConverter`

Answer (score 0):

After investigation I can make assumption that the behaviour of method message handling is changed because of [**Spring Cloud Stream**'s issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1527) and corresponding [**Spring Framework**'s issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17503?redirect=false). There is temporary overriden argument resolvers initialization in Spring Binder auto-configuration (bean definition on static method [`BinderFactoryConfiguration#messageHandlerMethodFactory`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/ce700c350d7f0889d9d19deac1e0903f4c94bcab/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/BinderFactoryConfiguration.java#L117)).

So first resolver in chain is `SmartPayloadArgumentResolver` which decides that the conversation is needed. This conversation is started and failed by `ApplicationJsonMessageMarshallingConverter`. The exception:

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"2019-09-04T01:26:20.202Z[UTC]"; line: 1, column: 6]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (String)"2019-09-04T01:26:20.202Z[UTC]"; line: 1, column: 6], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=2019-09-04T01:26:20.202Z[UTC], headers={spanTraceId=3f87b9afc373308a, spanId=3f87b9afc373308a, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[3f87b9afc373308a], spanId=[3f87b9afc373308a], spanSampled=[1]}, X-B3-SpanId=3f87b9afc373308a, X-B3-Sampled=1, X-B3-TraceId=3f87b9afc373308a, id=3fbe87e3-31c4-4d21-c3fb-506c018c0e25, spanSampled=1, timestamp=1567560380202}]
```

And as result I face error aforementioned in the question thrown from [`MethodReference`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.1.x/spring-expression/src/main/java/org/springframework/expression/spel/ast/MethodReference.java#L225).